# Rails: How to designate the date when saving the time in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

Today's date is set when I save the time in the DB.

For example, I set the time in the view as followings;

`from: 8:00`
`to  : 9:30`

these times are saved as follows;

`2016-04-03 08:00:00.000000`
`2016-04-03 09:30:00.000000`
(today is 2016-04-03)

What I'd like to do is to set the date to the designated date.

I have `depature date` in the same view.

If I choose `2016-05-12` for `depature date`, I'd like to save like this;

`2016-05-12 08:00:00.000000`
`2016-05-12 09:30:00.000000`

I use `bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails` to select `depature date`.

**schema.rb**

```
...
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.time     "from"
  t.time     "to"
...
```

**_schedule_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
<br>
  <%= f.label :departure_date %>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <%= f.text_field :departure_date, :value => (f.object.departure_date.strftime('%b/%d/%Y') if f.object.departure_date), class: 'form-control' %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({format:'MMM-DD-YYYY'});
    });
  </script>
  <br>
  <div id="room">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |a| %>
    <div id="room_<%= a.object.object_id %>">
      <p class="day-number-element-selector"><b>Day&nbsp;<%= a.index.to_i + 1 %></b></p>

      <%= a.simple_fields_for :events do |e| %>
        <span class="form-inline">
          <p>
            <%= e.input :from, label: false %>
            <%= e.input :to, label: false %>
          </p>
        </span>
        <%= e.input :title, label: false %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <%= a.link_to_add "Add event", :events, data: {target: "#room_#{a.object.object_id}"}, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <%= a.input :room %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **before_save** callback, something like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :assign_date

  private

  def assign_date
    assign_specific_date(to)
    assign_specific_date(from)
  end

  def assign_specific_date(date)
    date.month = departure_date.month
    date.year  = departure_date.year
    date.day   = departure_date.day
  end
end
```

Disclaimer: I'm definitely missing associations here, but this should give you an idea on how to implement what you need.

Comment: you can also use before_create which is running only when saving the first time, depend of your needs

Comment: Thank you for the clue, @Mario Carrion. I can save the selected date with using `before_save` callback.